# unable to import installed package in jupyter

Tags: python, import, pip

I have installed the package "vincent" as illustrated below.

[image]

However, I can't import it in Jupyter (and I don't understand the explanations elsewhere in Stackoverflow, so I figured I'd ask again.

[image]

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Are you certain that you're using the correct Python installation?

Comment: How do I check that?  Thanks!

Comment: _How do I check that? Thanks!_ Just search the web for something like "Python check current interpreter location".

Comment: K - will do.  Thank you.

Comment: It seems like the issue was indeed that Jupyter was using the wrong Python installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could mean that you installed `vincent` into a python editor that is not `jupyter`. Check to see if you have another python editor that has `vincent` installed in it.

---

UPDATE:

Here are the steps:

1. Launched Anaconda Prompt
2. Executed this statement: `conda install -c conda-forge vincent`

---

Be careful when using the base environment for anything. From the [documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html):

> Do not install, update, remove, or change dependencies. 
> This WILL lead to broken environments and inconsistent behavior.
>  Use at your own risk.

Comment: Not sure how to check that - would you mind guiding me a bit?  Thanks!

Comment: chack the location of the `pip` you use. It should be in a folder called `Scripts`.

Comment: I see a scripts file here:
C:\Users\n909858\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts
and there is a pip application file

Comment: Is `pip.exe` in it?

Comment: so yes, I think the pip file is the exe file and is saved in the scripts directory.

Comment: but I do not see a vincent file in the scripts folder - should I?

Comment: Nope. ---------

Comment: Is the scripts folder located in the package for `jupyter`?

Comment: I'm sorry - I am so confused.  I am using Jupyter through Anaconda and there is a scripts folder in the anaconda3 directory.  I do not see a jupyter folder in the anaconda3 directory

Comment: I found a few in the following directory:
C:\Users\n909858\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs

Comment: jupyter_client-5.3.3-py37_1,
jupyter_console-6.0.0-py37_0, 
jupyter_core-4.5.0-py_0,
jupyter-1.0.0-py37_7,
jupyterlab_server-1.0.6-py_0, and 
jupyterlab-1.1.4-pyhf63ae98_0

the first 2 have scripts folders but no pip in either of these folders

Comment: Since you are using anaconda, try conda install vincent

Comment: ok - so I think i was able to install it thanks to Ann Zen and AMC.  Step 1) I launched Anaconda Prompt (I wasn't doing this previously - I was only launching cmd from the start menu and I'm not sure whether this makes a difference. 2) I executed this statement: conda install -c conda-forge vincent 
This appears to have worked - THANK YOU

Comment: My pleasure. ---

Comment: @BuJay Be careful about where you're installing that package. Don't use the base environment for everything.

Comment: @AnnZen Can you amend your answer to provide some more context?

Comment: @AMC Done. ----

Answer (score 1):

You could install packages on Jupyter using following commands:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install vincent
```

Or you could install using following code

```
%%sh
http_proxy=http://10.245.5.340:8080  //change to your proxy localhost address
export http_proxy
https_proxy=https://10.245.5.340:8080 //change to your proxy localhost address
export https_proxy
pip install vincent
```